# Updating a bespoke WordPress Plugin automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, updates

I've recently created a `new plugin`, which is going to be on many sites (this is not hosted on WordPress for numerous reasons).

One big downfall of this - no updates.

I've read through:

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html

and

https://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/

but still not having any luck, as clicking 'check updates' just comes back with 'everything up to date'.

Does anyone have any experience with this? We would like to host this on bitbucket, but really can be anywhere as long as it can be private.

Any `links/experience` would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy solution to this.

https://kernl.us/

This allows updates via Bitbucket/github/gitlab. Easy to integrate and keeps the plugin in version control.